# Is there any way to get these 'canvas' lines drawn in one loop?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am simulating a page turn effect in html5 canvas.

On each page I am drawing lines to simulate lined paper.

These lines are drawn as the page is turned and in order to give natural perspective I am drawing them using quadratic curves based of several factors (page turn progress, closeness to the center of the page etc.. etc...)

The effect is very natural and looks great but I am looking for ways to optimize this.

Currently I am drawing every line twice, once for the actual line and once for a tiny highlight 1px below this line.  I am doing this like so:

```
// render lines (shadows)

          self.context.lineWidth = 0.35;

          var midpage = (self.PAGE_HEIGHT)/2;

          self.context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
          self.context.beginPath();

          for(i=3; i < 21; i++){
             var lineX = (self.PAGE_HEIGHT/22)*i;
             var curveX = (midpage - lineX) / (self.PAGE_HEIGHT);
             self.context.moveTo(foldX, lineX);                                       
             self.context.quadraticCurveTo(foldX, lineX + ((-verticalOutdent*4) * curveX), foldX - foldWidth - Math.abs(offset.x), lineX + ((-verticalOutdent*2) * curveX));

          }
          self.context.stroke();

 // render lines (highlights)
         self.context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)';
         self.context.beginPath();

         for(i=3; i < 21; i++){
              var lineX = (self.PAGE_HEIGHT/22)*i;
              var curveX = (midpage - lineX) / (self.PAGE_HEIGHT);
              self.context.moveTo(foldX, lineX+2);                                       
              self.context.quadraticCurveTo(foldX, lineX + ((-verticalOutdent*4) * curveX) + 1, foldX - foldWidth - Math.abs(offset.x), lineX + ((-verticalOutdent*2) * curveX) + 1);                                          
         }
         self.context.stroke();
```

As you can see I am opening a path, looping through each line, then drawing the path.  Then I repeat the whole process for the 'highlight' lines.

Is there any way to combine both of these operations into a single loop **without** drawing each line individually within the loop which would actually be far more expensive?

This is a micro-optimization, I am well aware of this.  However this project is a personal exercise for me in order to learn html5 canvas performance best practices/optimizations.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths can be stroked as many times as you like, they're not cleared when you call `.stroke()`, so:

1. create your path (as above)
2. `.stroke()` it
3. translate the context
4. change the colours
5. `.stroke()` it again

**EDIT** tried this myself - it didn't work - the second copy of the path didn't notice the translation of the coordinate space :(

It apparently *would* work if the path was created using `new Path()` as documented in the (draft) specification instead of the "current default path" but that doesn't appear to be supported in Chrome yet.